# Can someone help me with SQL Error: ORA-00904?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new at SQL and I need some help. I get this when I try to input some data into a table:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TRUKMĖ": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

This is the table I am trying to fill:

```
Name        Null     Type          
NR          NOT NULL NUMBER(2)     
PAVADINIMAS NOT NULL VARCHAR2(245) 
SVARBA               VARCHAR2(10)  
PRADŽIA              DATE          
TRUKMĖ               NUMBER(4)
```

And here is a sql:

```
INSERT INTO Projektai (
    Nr,
    Pavadinimas,
    Svarba,
    Pradžia,
    TRUKMĖ
    )
VALUES (
    Projektai_Vykdytojai_Nr.NEXTVAL,
    'Studentu apskaita',
    'Maža',
    (to_date('2005-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')),
    (12)
    );
```

I would realy appreciate if someone would help me. Thanks

Comment: I can't repeat? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f14d/1

Comment: I am new at everything here sosorry if I wont understand something :D

Comment: Locale issue? How do you specify collation or Unicode for Oracle?

Comment: Obviously, the non-standard characters may be the cause here. What's your database character set ? Also, why do you put number 12 between round brackets, in the `VALUES` section ?

Comment: @tvCa characters here is not a problem... I aready found it out. I put brackets there because I thought that if I separate that value it will resolve the problem... but afcorse it didn't... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that those foreign characters are not valid identifiers for the encoding of your database; Try enclosing the accented characters in quotes:

```
INSERT INTO Projektai (
    Nr,
    Pavadinimas,
    Svarba,
    "Pradžia",
    "TRUKMĖ"
) VALUES (
    Projektai_Vykdytojai_Nr.NEXTVAL,
    'Studentu apskaita',
    'Maža',
    to_date('2005-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
    12
);
```

I also removed some unnecessary brackets.

Comment: `"PRADŽIA"` would need to be quoted in uppercase though, based on the table description?

Comment: I already found a problem, but thanks anyway :)
by the way foregin characters aren't a problem. It works with other tables :)

Comment: @mantas if you found the problem then please post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Bohemian♦ It wont work for others because it still gives errors but it still managed to insert a data into a table. I don't undertand howI did it sow I wont postit. I gess it is normal not to post something i don't understand

Comment: @Axel: the error says column TRUKME is wrong, and that one is OK according to the case. There's some other problem..